# onClick function for multiple buttons

Tags: java, class, kotlin, methods, onclicklistener

How would I set an onclick function (or onclicklistner) to multiple buttons? The reason being, is I don't want to have to write this same code for each button, where the only different variable would be "Feeling" for each button.

This is my code: *(Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I'm just experimenting right now!)*

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("Users")
        val userLocation = "New York"
        val userId = myRef.push().key
        val info = Users(Feeling = "Good", Location=userLocation)

        if (userId != null) {
            myRef.child(userId).setValue(info)
        }
    }
```

From the Class file:

```
class Users(val Feeling: String, val Location: String) {

    constructor() : this("","") {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click listener receives a `view` as parameter, you can use that to identify the button by it's id,

```
val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { button ->
    val feeling = when (button.id) {
        R.id.button_1 -> /* get feeling */
        R.id.button_2 -> /* ... */
        ...
        else -> return
    // use the feeling to do whatever you need
}
```

You would then set this click listener to all your buttons.

Edit:
to set the click listener, you have different options. You can use `findViewById` for each of them, using a `binding` object and then bind the click listener, it depends on your setup.

For instance

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(clickListener)
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(clickListener)
}
```

Comment: How would I set the click listener to all buttons?

Comment: Sorry about the trouble, but where would I use the val "feeling"? If this is too much trouble, don't worry about it.